# How may my app determine at run-time the version of the .NET framework it is running under?

Tags: .net

Note that this question refers to the version running the app, not all versions installed, and to the framework (as shown in VS as "target framework") not the run-time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Version property of Environment class. Concating Major and minor version number will give you framework version (e.g. 2.0). 
MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version.aspx

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't give the framework version - it gives the CLR version.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the currenly running CLR version, use Novakov's method (e.g. 4.0.30319.239):

```
Environment.Version
```

If you want to know the CLR version the project was built against (e.g. 4.0.0.0), use the following:

```
GetType().Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies().Single(a => a.Name == "mscorlib").Version
```

This may give you a different value than the currently running CLR, since older version assemblies may be running in a newer versions of the CLR. Note that "Target Framework" of 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 will all return 2.0.0.0 here, since they all were all built against version 2.0 of the CLR.

You can perform an additional check that may reveal that a CLR 2.0 project was built using a target framework of 3.5:

```
typeof(ConsoleSandbox.Program).Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()
    .SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name == "System.Core") == null
```

The above expression will evaluate to true if the target framework is 3.5 (or 4.0 if mscorlib is 4.0.0.0) and will evaluate to false if the target framework is 2.0 or 3.0 or if nothing from System.Core.dll was used (e.g. a 2.0/3.0 project that was upgraded).

If you explain the need behind your question, it might be possible to give you a better answer.